# Providing an independent proof for change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a smooth change of variables $\psi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ where $\psi(x,y) = (x, g(x,y))$ and $g$ is strictly increasing with respect to its second variable. For $K = [a,b]\times[0,1]$, explicitly find $\psi(K)$ and provide an independent proof of the change of variables formula $\int_{\psi(K)} f(\vec x)\,\mathrm d\vec x=\int_K f(\psi(\vec u))\lvert\mathrm{det} D\psi(\vec u)\rvert\,\mathrm d\vec u$.

Things I know:
$$\psi(K) = \{(x,y):a\le x\le b, g(x,0)\le y\le g(x,1)\}$$
$$D\psi=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
g_x & g_y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathrm{det}D\psi=g_y\gt 0$$

Now I need to show that the change of variables formula holds:
$$\int_{\psi(k)}f(\vec x)\,\mathrm d\vec x = \int_a^b \int_{g(x,0)}^{g(x,1)} f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
$$\int_K f(\psi(\vec u))\lvert\mathrm{det} D\psi(\vec u)\rvert\,\mathrm d\vec u = \int_a^b \int_0^1 f(u, g(u,v))g_v\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du$$

and now I'm not quite sure how to show that these two equations are equivalent.

The way my book proves the change of variables formula, I believe it would be sufficient to show that

$$\mathrm{vol}\,\psi(K)=\lvert\,\mathrm{det}D\psi(\vec x)\rvert\mathrm{vol}\,K+\epsilon\,\mathrm{vol}\,K$$

but I get stuck trying to find the area of $\psi(K)$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{area}\,\psi(K)&=\iint_{\psi(K)}\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \\
&=\int_a^b \int_{g(x,0)}^{g(x,1)}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_a^b (g(x,1)-g(x,0))\,\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_a^b g_y(x,\theta)\,\mathrm dx, \qquad\theta \in [0,1]
\end{align}
$$

and after that I'm not sure how I can continue evaluating the integral.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proving it directly:

We have the following from above:
$$\begin{align}
(1) &\int_{\psi(k)}f(\vec x)\,\mathrm d\vec x = \int_a^b \int_{g(x,0)}^{g(x,1)} f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx \\
(2) &\int_K f(\psi(\vec u))\lvert\mathrm{det} D\psi(\vec u)\rvert\,\mathrm d\vec u = \int_a^b \int_0^1 f(u, g(u,v))g_v\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du
\end{align}$$

Let $y = g(x,w)$ in (1):

$$=\int_a^b \int_0^1 f(x,g(x,w))g_w\,\mathrm dw\,\mathrm dx$$
Which is the same as (2).